# Split multiple delimiter into same columns in python pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, split, delimiter

I have this data

```
wards='Shasha/Akowonjo; Egbeda/Alimosho; Idimu/Isheri Olofin; Akesan; 
Ikotun/Ijegun; Egbe/Agodo; Igando/Egan; Ipaja North; Ipaja South; 
Ayobo/Ijon Village (Camp David); Pleasure/Oke-Odo; Abule- 
Egba/Aboru/Meiran/Alagbado'
```

how can I split them into a columns since they have 2 delimiters (; and /)

I want the wards to appear in a single column and on different rows.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: Tried some many options online, but then all gave wrong answers, but @jammin0921 just gave me the clue and the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at using the [re](/questions/tagged/re) python package. See below:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['wards'] = re.split('; |/', wards)
```